# Convert object value to upper case

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object like below. I want to convert all the keys to Uppercase. I am looking for some solution like

```
JSON.stringify(jsonObj).replace();
```

Can anyone please help me with the actual regex to do the same?

Input:

```
{"data": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "first_name": "eve",
      "last_name": "holt",
      "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg"
    }]}
```

Output I am expecting:

```
{"DATA": [
    {
      "ID": 4,
      "FIRST_NAME": "eve",
      "LAST_NAME": "holt",
      "AVATAR": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg"
    }]}
```

Comment: Why regex? Why not loops? Note, `JSON.stringify` will remove all functions

Comment: You want to convert all the ***keys***…?! You should *not* do this after stringification; use a recursive function to do this *before*.

Comment: `.replace(/("[^"]+":)/g, (_,b) => b.toUpperCase())` - works for the sample

Comment: `Note, JSON.stringify will remove all functions` since JSON doesn't allow functions, that's not an issue

Comment: Why on earth would you need or want to do something like this?

Comment: @torazaburo - to do the inverse of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069896/convert-json-object-values-to-uppercase of course

Comment: If you don't know the difference between "keys" and "values", you are going to have a very hard time making much progress on your JavaScript journey. I suggest going back and reading and re-reading tutorials, intros, and getting-starteds before posting more questions here. Perhaps as part of your study you'll discover why it is such a bad idea to think about manipulating little languages such as JSON with regexps, which is designed for string manipulation.

Answer (score 7):

Make use of [`JSON.stringify`'s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) replacer argument:

```js
var obj = {
  "data": [{
    "id": 4,
    "first_name": "eve",
    "last_name": "holt",
    "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg"
  }]
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, value) {
  if (typeof value === 'object' && value && !Array.isArray(value)) {
    return Object.keys(value).reduce(function(obj, k) {
      obj[k.toUpperCase()] = value[k];
      return obj;
    }, {});
  }
  return value;
}, 2));
```

---

Of course if you actually want an object, not JSON, just use

```
var newObj = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(o, k) {
  o[k.toUpperCase()] = obj[k];
  return o;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json-case-convertor`,
https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-case-convertor/v/1.0.3

This will handle any type of object (simple object, nested objects etc)

```
npm install json-case-convertor

const jcc = require('json-case-convertor')
jcc.upperCaseKeys(jsonData)
```